# Problems creating SAAJ object model in SOAP request

Tags: soap, jmeter, base64, saaj

I have a `JMeter` test case which contains `SOAP` requests with various files attached to these. So same request is sent with different files. 
It is working properly with some files, but it gives `HTTP 500` error code with following message:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Problems creating SAAJ object model</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I checked raw request and found it is correct syntactically, only difference is the file, which is attached in `Base64` encoded format.

Comment: Could you provide more elements (jmeter.log, test plan structure with zoom on concerned parts, server logs...)

Comment: Can you show error in server log?

Comment: @user7294900 : Sorry, I can't, I have no access to server logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the elements you provide it is very hard to say anything.

But I guess that there is some kind of relation between uploaded file and the request content which leads to the server error.

Unless you show the server logs, we cannot help more.

Another option is that your request uses an incorrect header or parameter in relation to the attached file. To further investigate you should show your request (GUI + Content).

Comment: Yes, it is caused by some attachments. Request is working with some files and fails with these error message in some cases. Request is correct syntactically in all cases.